# Do parameterized statements actually change that data that is stored in the database to prevent SQL Injection?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

My question is basically this: If I use a parameterized statement/prepared statement to insert a user input string into a table, then get that value later and use it for dynamically constructing a table's column values, does that leave me open to SQLInjection?

Specific example:

If i store a user's input string into a table using a parameterized statement, then select that TEXT from that table and store it in a local variable (String localVariable) in my program and CREATE a table with something like:

```
"CREATE TABLE InjectFree (" + localVariable + " TEXT)"
```

would my localVariable be free of injectable sql code? I know there are alternatives (and will probably use an alternative just to be on the safe side), but I guess I'm just wondering what parameterizing a value actually does and what effect it has on the data being stored in the table.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Java in this case, but does it really matter? I'm more interested in knowing what happens to a String once it's inserted into a database using a parameterized statement then actually appending that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use parameterised queries the query and the data are supplied to the database separately.  This has several effects...

- It allows the RDBMS to see that the query is identical to previous instances of that query.  *(If you embed the data as static values in the query string, the RDBMS will not see that the query is the same and only the data has changed.)*  This allows execution plan re-use and other beneficial characteristic of the RDBMS.
- It simplifies the data validation.  This is relevant to injection attacks.  No matter what values are substituted into the parameter, the data is always just data.  It will never be treated as part of the query.

This latter point, however, also means that you ***can't*** do this...

```
INSERT INTO @tableName(@fieldName) VALUES (@dataValue)
```

Each parameter is treated as a data item.  It isn't a loosely bound script, the value in `@tableName` won't be substituted into the script.  The query ***must*** be hard-coded with the table and field names.  Only true data items can be passed as parameters.

This often feels like a limitation to users of java script, etc.  It is, however, the mecahnism that prtects you from SQL Injection attacks.  It's a good thing :)

This means that to allow user defined Data Definition Lanaguage *(Such as a CREATE TABLE)* you need to concatenate the different parts of the string together yourself.  And virtually no matter what you do to protect yourself from a SQL Injection Attack here, some-one will find a way through.

As soon as you allow a user to specify table names, field names, etc, you become immediately open to attack.  The ***only*** safe way is to have a white-list of allowable strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Yes, having a white list of allowable strings is the alternative I chose. Basically just have another table that I have a user input as a column and table names that I've determined as a table name.

Answer (score 3):

you will be in danger.

the parameterized insert will protect from injection on that otriginal insert statement, but not from the next use.